# Basic auth - authorization header not being added for some requests

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, axios, basic-authentication

It's my first approach in implementing simplest version of basic auth and I can't get it to work. The authentication is working only for the first request.

Frontend: React + Axios (withCredentials: true), available on http://localhost:3000

Backend: Express + express-basic-auth, available on http://localhost:3004

```
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { [ENV.user]: ENV.password },
    challenge: true,
    realm: 'Authorize',
}));
```

Headers for every request:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
```

I use `challenge` flag, because I want to show the native browser prompt for authorization.

The app is simple. First fired request gets the list (GET) of DB records and its rendered. Each of the item on list has an action button that does some PUT request.

So, when the first GET request happens, I'm asked for the credentials (just like planned).

After sending correct ones, 200 is returned, all good.
It works for another GET request that is sent right after it.

Unfortunately, all other requests (the PUT actions) do not work. They throw 401 on OPTIONS. The authorization header is empty when console.logging on backend, indeed, but I thought/read that the browser should set it automatically. It does it for the first request, I can refresh and the list is fetched, so I'd think it will be attached for everything else too. I remember doing the same with htaccess and it worked out of box.

What am I doing wrong? Looks like Chrome attaches the authorization header only for GET requests...? Ignoring all others? Or do I miss something.

How can I make it work without writing custom login screen, but instead using the browsers functionality (`challenge: true`)?

Comment: I think you should attach the rest of the code, in that form might be too little information

Answer (score 0):

it's because of other HTTP verbs other than GET/HEAD/POST (such as PUT and DELETE) have to enable CORS pre-flight to pass through the CORS restriction. I suggest you to use the expressjs/cors npm package to deal with your problem. https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options

**After you install the package** replace your res.headers() with

```
var express = require("express")
var cors = require("cors")
var app = express()

app.use(cors()) //This line does the same with your res.headers() code block
app.options("*",cors()) //This line enables CORS pre-flight requests
```

You can read more information about this under **Enabling CORS Pre-Flight** in the link I posted above, good luck.